# Stopping a Thread in Multithreaded Python code

Tags: python, multithreading

I am working on multithreading in python i could not achieve to stop individual threads. The code is below. How can i achieve this? Thanks...

```
from threading import Thread
import threading
import time


class MyThread(threading.Thread):
    def stop(self):
        self.stopped = True
        print ("working")
    stopped=True


def func(argument):
    t = threading.current_thread()
    while not t.stopped:
        print(argument)
        time.sleep(0.5)


a = MyThread(target=func,args=("1",))
b = MyThread(target=func,args=("2",))
c = MyThread(target=func,args=("3",))
d = MyThread(target=func,args=("4",))
a.daemon = True
b.daemon = True
c.daemon = True
d.daemon = True
a.start()
b.start()
c.start()
d.start()

time.sleep(3)
b.stop()
c.stop()
d.stop()
```

After execution of this code, a thread must be alive and still running the function but all of the threads stop.

Answer (score 3):

Clearly you expect that thread `a` should not stop as you have not called `a.stop()`.  However, you have a class scoped attribute `stopped` as well:

```
class MyThread(threading.Thread):
    def stop(self):
        self.stopped = True
        print ("working")

    # !! this is a class level attribute !!
    stopped=True
```

Thus, `MyThread.stopped` is `True`.  When you ask an instance of `MyThread` for the `stopped` attribute using `self.stopped` it will:

- first check if the attribute `stopped` exists on the *instance*;
- else check if the attribute exists on the type `MyThread`

Thus in your case, `MyThread().stopped` is **always** `True`

Comment: then, which method should i use?

Comment: I think you want to initialize stopped = False in your class definition.

Answer (score 0):

I figure it out the solution and wanted to share.

```
from threading import Thread
import threading
import time


class MyThread(threading.Thread):
    stop = False


def func(argument):
    t = threading.current_thread()
    while True:
        if not t.stop:
            print(argument)
            time.sleep(0.5)


a = MyThread(target=func,args=("1",))
b = MyThread(target=func,args=("2",))
c = MyThread(target=func,args=("3",))
d = MyThread(target=func,args=("4",))
a.start()
b.start()
c.start()
d.start()
time.sleep(3)
b.stop = True
c.stop = True
d.stop = True
time.sleep(3)
b.stop = False
```